# Why is the address of System::String not changing despite GC running its cycle?

Tags: c++-cli

I have the following code that I am using to see the functioning of GC (Garbage Collector).

```
#include <stdio.h>

ref class CData
{
public:
    System::String^ str;
    int age;

    CData(System::String^% string)
    {
        str = string;
    }
};

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) // ((1))
        gcnew CData(i.ToString());

    System::String^ str1 = L"TestString";
    CData^ d = gcnew CData(str1);
    d->age = 100;

    interior_ptr<System::String^> pint1 = &d->str;
    interior_ptr<int> pint2 = &d->age;

    printf("%p  %p\r\n", pint1, pint2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        gcnew CData(i.ToString());

    printf("%p  %p\r\n", pint1, pint2);
        
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran the code, the result I got was as follows.

**012FF40C  0395013C**

**012FF40C  03474868**

As can be clearly seen, the address of **"age" member** in memory changes where as the one for **"str" member** of the class does not. According to the Microsoft documentation, as a compaction cycle is run, memory is collected from the dead objects and the live object are moved to a newer address to compact the heap. I also realized that GC does not like to mess with interned strings. So, I tried changing

```
System::String^ str1 = L"TestString";
```

to

```
System::String^ str1 = System::IO::File::ReadAllText(L"TestString.txt");
```

so that str1 is not interned. However, the results were the same. Address for "age" changed, but not for "str" member.

The next thing I tried was to get the interior buffer using PtrToStringChars, but to no avail. The results were the same.

I am failing to understand why it is so despite reading many forums, documentations, and QnAs on the internet. Can someone explain to me this behavior?

Comment: Note how different the pointer values are, tells you that the string allocation is special.  This is micro-optimized inside the CLR, the jitter generates a call to CORINFO_HELP_NEWSFAST().  Documented in the CLR source code as "allocator for small, non-finalizer, non-array object".  Very fast indeed in the workstation version of the CLR, JIT_TrialAllocSFastSP is less than a page of loop-less hand-crafted assembly code.  Exactly how it interacts with the regular GC is not obvious to me, micro-optimization code is never easy to read.  But it googles really well.

Comment: What the different pointer values tell me is that you failed to create an `interior_ptr`, you got a temporary.  (of the `System::String^`, not the `System::String` it points to).  You should be able to do `*pint1 = L"abc";` and see a change to `d->str`.... mind testing that?

Comment: Interestingly, when I did that, it changed the result of d->str. In fact, If I enter a string longer than the original string ("Test" in this case) such as "Testing 123", it increases the length without crashing the application. While this is all intriguing, I'm not sure what this means. Since my app is not crashing, I think it is just allocating a new string (gcnew System::String(L"Testing 123")) and assigning it to the interior_ptr I got. @BenVoigt, can you explain to me what all this result means.

Comment: @HansPassant

So, JIT does a lot in the background for a String allocation which might be related mostly to optimization. Understood. But now I'm confused about the effect of GCHandle now, mainly about a pinned one. Since the address is evidently not changing despite GC running its magic, what effect would GCHandle::Alloc(str, GCHandleType::Pinned) have on the String? Would it not render GCHandle (Pinned) needless in this case?

Comment: @MarshallLighter: `d->str` has type `System::String^` -- it's a tracking pointer to a `System::String` instance.  `&d->str` therefore is a double-pointer, and can be used to make `d->str` point to an entirely different `System::String`, which is what you did.  So you really do have an interior_ptr to a field inside `d` and it isn't clear to me why two such interior_ptr (one to `&d->str`, one to `&d->age`) shouldn't have addresses very close to each other.  I guess it's possible the garbage collector ran in between and compacted things, changing the address.

Comment: Another thing to try: besides `printf("%p  %p\r\n", pint1, pint2);` do `printf("%p  %p\r\n", pint1, (void*)nullptr); printf("%p  %p\r\n", (void*)nullptr, pint2); printf("%p  %p\r\n", (void*)pint1, (void*)pint2);`  It's possible that `interior_ptr` is larger than a normal pointer and doesn't print correctly with `%p`.